# What is a "Hive"?

Tags: microsoft-account, windows-live

Has anyone figured out what the function of Windows Phone hives are? I personally am part of the Palladium 7 hive. I originally thought it was for technical grouping (making updates and fixed easier to roll out), but its a wild guess.

If you don't know what your hive is, open the app "Outsider" (former "...I'm a WP7") and you'll see the hive you are assigned to.

Comment: A "Hive" is typically a registry area...I will keep looking into it though. On a side note, here is a list of them http://www.imawp7.com/imawp7/HiveNames.aspx

Comment: You can swap hives with another user. So it sounds like a geographical/social network grouping. Not much info floating around about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the app `I'm a WP<sup>7</sup> and go to my Hive, swipe over to "About" and you will see that (emphasis mine)

> A WP7 Hive is an **arbitrary grouping of users** that gets assigned
>   when you register your Windows Phone. What is the purpose of a Hive?
>   Well, honestly we don't know, and **no one at Microsoft seems to
>   know**, but we are lucky enough to have the secret formula to figure
>   it out....We are using this sneaky information to make it easier (and
>   more fun!) to connect with other Windows Phone users worldwide.

Now, that leads you to believe that it is something some developer at Microsoft implemented, and has since left leaving no one to know what they are. Although possible, I am too cynical to believe that.

What do I think it is?....The developer of the app made them up. Yup, sorry but I don't see anything on Bing/Google/WP sites/(or even asking some people on the WP team) that knows what they are LET ALONE heard of them.

I'm going to preface this next statement with a "This site is not for developers", **but** as a developer I have not even seen this information available in the API, and since this is an official app, I know it is only using legit means to do it.

So what are they? Well, I think the app is using them to `make it easier (and more fun!) to connect with other Windows Phone users worldwide`...a gimmick

I could be wrong, but that is the only thing I could come up with. The only other possibility I can think of is they are actually called something else, and the app developer chose to use "Hive". That would explain why nothing comes up (except this thread!) in a search.

Answer (score 1):

User profile hives are located under the HKEY_USERS key on WP devices. They seem to be part of a data tree for fast data mining... Or in this case its probly for a update protocol.